# What are the requirements for a second bachelors if I already have one in an unrelated field?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, second-degree

For context, I’ve lived in the USA my whole life. I currently have a bachelors degree from a state university in business administration. At 31 I’m considering pursuing a degree in mathematics. I was curious what the requirements are likely to be for such a degree. I understand there will be differences from school to school but any general guidelines would be greatly appreciated. Presumably, I would be able to transfer most of my general education credits over and be able to focus on just the math requirements which would greatly reduce the necessary credit hours. I work full time and have a family so this would be an online degree as well.

Comment: You need to talk to a specific institution about what will transfer. The admissions office should be able to give you solid, and specific, advice. But in the US, it is likely that lots of stuff will transfer.

Comment: This is actually off topic for two reasons. It is about undergraduate admissions and it depends too much on individual factors.

Answer (score 2):

*Edited to ad clarity and move the comment about non-degree related courses to the top since it was missed by multiple people*

Assuming you go to a school that recognizes the other degree as valid you will need the courses required for that degree plus any delta in the non-degree courses. The second isn't likely to be more than a course or 2 but depends on the school and could be quite a lot. An appointment with an admissions rep for the specific school before you do the application process will save you time and money.

Assuming you took 0 hours of calc or higher and you are getting it in the same state that you got your first degree - it might look like this:

School A: Pure Math 45 hours. No special requirements beyond those required by the state. You just need the 45 hours.

School B: Pure Math 40 hours. Same state but also mandates Left Handed Underwater BAsket Weaving 1 and 2. 1 has a pre-req of SCUBA 1 and 2 has a prereq of SCUBA 2. Those are 4 hours each. Total is 56 hours.

You can likely make an appointment with an admissions rep to have a detailed conversation over the phone or in person before you even spend the $50 application fee to apply for acceptance. That will help to ensure that everything will transfer (in the event you do have some required classes) and prevent a surprise like 16 hours of Underwater Left-Handed Basket Weaving that you haven't already taken but that everyone at that institute has to take - even though it isn't specifically part of the major.

You know you can also just go straight for the Masters Degree and not bother with a second bachelors right? Check into that if you haven't, it might even have fewer hours and you might qualify for financial aid that you wouldn't qualify for since you have a bachelors already. If there is concern about your ability to do the masters, see if they do a masters certificate with the classes that go into the masters. After you get a couple As and have met the professors, ask for a letter of recommendation and apply for the masters. Those classes definitely transfer and getting accepted after already passing the classes shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Thanks, Rodger! Although I minored in underwater basket weaving the first time around so that shouldn’t be an issue

Comment: +1 for going straight for the masters. It will be difficult for pure math (it seems like you have been out for a few years, and that skill does not often retain well in industry).   However, it will typically have a higher payoff for you personally and may take less time (in years - not in hours/week).

Comment: @Buffy not sure which part is wrong. It was an example. I have no idea what the requirements are. Are you saying that if you get a degree from Univ X and Univ Y recognizes it as a valid degree that Univ Y is going to make someone take anything beyond the requirements of the major? That isn't generally the case but even when it is, I thought I specifically addressed that with the comment about basket weaving. Can you add some clarity to what you meant or what I need to fix with that so it is more accurate?

Comment: @Buffy: *the general education requirements are not identical over the US* -- Indeed, as an example, 2 semesters of physical education courses (e.g. tennis, basketball, jogging, etc.) and passing a swimming test was required where I (initially) was an undergraduate.